# Is it possible to employ an autochanger for generating a unified storage volume from multiple LTFS formatted tapes in Linux?

Tags: linux, backup, tape, lto

I'm exploring storage options involving LTO tapes. Given the potential for massive data storage that these tapes provide, I'm interested in utilizing multiple LTO tapes simultaneously in a storage array.

I have access to an autochanger, a NEO XL40 and one LTO-9 drive and I'm wondering if it is possible to create a volume spanning multiple drives. The end goal is to streamline access and management of the data across these tapes, essentially viewing and handling them as a singular storage unit.

Any guidance or recommendations about whether this is feasible, and if so, how to accomplish it would be greatly appreciated. Are there specific tools or steps involved in this process, or potential issues I should be aware of?